# Row level permissions in sails

Tags: sails.js

I have started working on a project and have decided to use Sails.js to build an API. I have no previous experience with Sails and that is why I need your recommendation.

I need to implement row level permissions for many Models. For example, imagine that I want to allow to perform an update only to the creator of that record. What do you suggest in terms of performance and feasibility?

I had been thinking about implementing a policy and before perform the operation, read the record to identify if the requester was the creator. But I am not really sure if it would be a good idea because of the effort of override every method and also in terms of performance.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module for permissions : https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-permissions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use policies....

sails.js actually handles this requirement very gracefully.

Policies allow very specific programmatic control over (what|who) can (create|read|update|delete) anything.

Policies are clean, organized, and are easy to reason about...

[Read the docs!](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/policies)

Comment: Actually they aren't very graceful in handling row level permissions. Things like: reducing the collection of items visible based on a comparison of the current user and related records of the current collection. @edzon: row level permissions (done properly) are always going to be intensive, you'll need to track models and recordIds, maintain a list of who can do what with what instance of certain models. Policies can't really handle this elegantly. Instead look at `sails-permissions`

Comment: @airtonix this was posted back in May. If you look closely you will see `sails-permissions` didn't exist until August. After a quick look, I think I'll stick with policies.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't verified any of the new changes yet, but a recently accepted pull-request in sails-permissions might be of use to you.

[Support transitive permissions #64](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-permissions/issues/64)