# Row level permissions in sails.js

Tags: mysql, ember.js, sails.js, acl, waterline

I need row-level permissions in sails. I already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436757/row-level-permissions-in-sails) and at other threads, but everybody says to just use policies.
But what I need isn't just limiting the ability to do e.g. find/update all elements of a table but to have permissions per database row that consider associations for permissions.

It would be great if the permissions support blueprints like the [ember data adapter](https://github.com/bmac/ember-data-sails-adapter), nested create/update/find (with populate) and sockets.

So for example:

```
GET /:model/:id
```

should return and populate with such entries where certain associated conditions are met.

So for example, we have 4 models:

```
User              (columns: id, name, email, pwd_hash, ...)
Project           (columns: id, client, name, ...) 
UserAssignment    (columns: id, user, project, user_perms, ...)  
Client            (columns: id, name, ...)
```

`User` and `Project` are linked through `UserAssignment` - an advanced MM-Table. (`User`s may have special user_perms to different projects, such as read,write,manage). And a `Project` always has one `Client`.

Here's the corresponding sails models:

```
// User.js
attributes: {
  name: 'string'
}

// Project.js
attributes: {
  name: 'string',
  client: {
    model: 'client'
  },
  userAssignments: {
    collection: 'userAssignment',
    via: 'project'
  }
}

// UserAssignment.js
attributes: {
  userPerms: 'integer',
  user: {
    model:'user'
  },
  project: {
    model:'project'
  }
}

// Client.js
attributes: {
  name: 'string',
  projects: {
    collection: 'project',
    via: 'client'
  }
}
```

So lets say the `User` with the ID=1 wants to access a list of `Clients` he is allowed to see, he calls

```
GET /clients/
```

Speaking in SQL:

```
SELECT client.* 
FROM client 
INNER JOIN project ON project.client = client.id 
INNER JOIN user_assignment ON project.id = user_assignment.project
WHERE user_assignment.user = 1 and user_perms > 4
GROUP BY client.id;
```

And then also if we have certain `Project` managers, they can update associated `UserAssignment`s etc.
Basically I thought the permissions could be based on role associations.

I tried several ways to implement this functionality. I tried `_permission_read`, `_permission_write` columns for all rows and other stuff like using populates for this but nothing seems to work right.

The above example is just a excerpt of many different kinds of models which I can filter based on SQL couldn't do nicely with Sails/Waterline.

- Do I need custom SQL queries for this?
- Is it possible to do this neatly with Sails?
- Do I misunderstand policies and is there a way to implement such requirements with them?
- Or shall I use SQL views instead of tables?

Thanks in advance!